# twitter library on iOS6

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter, ios6

I am trying to make our App work on iOS6, but there is a problem related to twitter library. It seems like twitter library does not support the new armv7s architecture, so whenever I try to build the application on a device, Xcode will complain that "file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice:.../Twitter/Twitter+OAuth/Libraries & Headers/libOAuth.a for architecture armv7s". Does any one know how to make this thing work? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your minimum iOS target is iOS5, you should be using the native Twitter support that was made available with iOS5.

If you still need to use this third-party Twitter library, you can simply remove armv7s from the list of architectures to be built from your app's build settings.

[image]

I did this briefly after iOS6 and Xcode 4.5 was released but before some third-party libraries I use had released updates with armv7s slices.